# Can't get phpmyadmin to work. session_start(): Failed to decode session object. Session has been destroyed

Tags: session, phpmyadmin

I've been trying to get phpmyadmin5-php83 to work on my freebsd 13.2 server.

I've managed to get the login screen to work, but when I try to login I get an error:
`phpMyAdmin - Error
Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.

session_start(): Failed to decode session object. Session has been destroyed`

I believe it has something to do with permissions.
I don't know where the php error log is located.

Can anyone assist me with this?

sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/www/phpMyAdmin

z@myrkur:/usr/local/www $ sudo tvar/log/php-fpm.log

```
`[27-Sep-2023 06:16:50] NOTICE: configuration file /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf test is successful

[27-Sep-2023 06:16:50] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 58418
[27-Sep-2023 06:16:50] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[27-Sep-2023 12:46:57] NOTICE: configuration file /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf test is successful

[27-Sep-2023 12:46:57] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 91927
[27-Sep-2023 12:46:57] NOTICE: ready to handle connections`
```

z@myrkur:/usr/local/www $ sudo tail /var/log/php-scripts.log
shows nothing.

edit 01.10.2023 23:07:

z@myrkur:~ $ sudo tail /var/log/httpd-error.log

```
Password:
[Sun Oct 01 22:51:12.714450 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 82594] AH00163: Apache/2.4.57 (FreeBSD) PHP/8.3.0alpha2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Oct 01 22:51:12.714563 2023] [core:notice] [pid 82594] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/local/sbin/httpd -D NOHTTPACCEPT'
[Sun Oct 01 22:51:25.550426 2023] [authz_host:error] [pid 82697] [client 104.28.226.138:12356] AH01753: access check of '.myrkur.net' to /phpmyadmin/ failed, reason: unable to get the remote host name
[Sun Oct 01 22:51:25.550578 2023] [authz_host:error] [pid 82697] [client 104.28.226.138:12356] AH01753: access check of '.myrkur.net' to /phpmyadmin/index.php failed, reason: unable to get the remote host name
[Sun Oct 01 22:52:06.572645 2023] [authz_host:error] [pid 82803] [client 104.28.194.138:14745] AH01753: access check of '.myrkur.net' to /phpmyadmin/ failed, reason: unable to get the remote host name
[Sun Oct 01 22:52:06.572800 2023] [authz_host:error] [pid 82803] [client 104.28.194.138:14745] AH01753: access check of '.myrkur.net' to /phpmyadmin/index.php failed, reason: unable to get the remote host name
[Sun Oct 01 22:52:14.383309 2023] [authz_host:error] [pid 82893] [client 104.28.194.138:14594] AH01753: access check of '.myrkur.net' to /phpmyadmin/index.php failed, reason: unable to get the remote host name
[Sun Oct 01 23:04:21.438995 2023] [authz_host:error] [pid 82699] [client 104.28.226.138:12772] AH01753: access check of '.myrkur.net' to /phpmyadmin/ failed, reason: unable to get the remote host name
[Sun Oct 01 23:04:21.439104 2023] [authz_host:error] [pid 82699] [client 104.28.226.138:12772] AH01753: access check of '.myrkur.net' to /phpmyadmin/index.php failed, reason: unable to get the remote host name
[Sun Oct 01 23:04:30.958554 2023] [authz_host:error] [pid 82697] [client 104.28.194.138:14469] AH01753: access check of '.myrkur.net' to /phpmyadmin/index.php failed, reason: unable to get the remote host name
```

---

z@myrkur:~ $ sudo tail /var/log/httpd-access.log

```
104.28.194.138 - - [01/Oct/2023:22:52:06 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4442
104.28.194.138 - - [01/Oct/2023:22:52:14 +0000] "POST /phpmyadmin/index.php?route=/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1213
104.28.194.138 - - [01/Oct/2023:22:52:34 +0000] "-" 408 -
104.28.226.138 - - [01/Oct/2023:23:01:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 371
104.28.226.138 - - [01/Oct/2023:23:01:53 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 196
104.28.226.138 - - [01/Oct/2023:23:04:21 +0000] "GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4440
104.28.194.138 - - [01/Oct/2023:23:04:30 +0000] "POST /phpmyadmin/index.php?route=/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1213
104.28.194.138 - - [01/Oct/2023:23:04:50 +0000] "-" 408 -
87.250.224.16 - - [01/Oct/2023:23:07:23 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 196
87.250.224.8 - - [01/Oct/2023:23:07:23 +0000] "GET /wot/u%20wot/ HTTP/1.1" 404 196
```

edit2:

```
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
#    Require all denied
Require ip 192.168.0.0/24
Require all granted
</Directory>

/usr/local/etc/apache24/httpd.conf: 561 lines, 21589 characters.
z@myrkur:/usr/local/www/apache24/data $ sudo service apache24 restart
Performing sanity check on apache24 configuration:
Syntax OK
Stopping apache24.
Waiting for PIDS: 14508.
Performing sanity check on apache24 configuration:
Syntax OK
Starting apache24.
```

tried this, same error. Any ideas?

Comment: Check your web server's (eg nginx, Apache, etc) error log file

Comment: I've updated the post. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you've got some [mod_authz_host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html) configuration that is failing a check

Comment: tried editing the <Directory /> thing in /usr/local/etc/apache24/httpd.conf to no avail.

Comment: Downgrade to PHP 8.2. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install MyBB the other day with Apache on FreeBSD. There were some modules that MyBB required me to enable for it to work. I enabled them in the config file by uncommenting the LoadModule lines. I restarted the server, but MyBB still refused to work, and there were no errors from Apache if I remember correctly.

It turns out, I had to pkg install the php modules separately. Even if they were enabled in the httpd.config, if I hadn't separately pkg installed them, it would not work. I believe I used mod_php83 for php btw.